# Как по событию убирать/добавлять элементы в комбобокс?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть комбобоксы, и в них значение постоянно меняются. Как сделать, чтобы комбобокс сверял поступающие ему значение со своим? Допустим ему приходит значение из другого метода, и если он такого значение не найдет то он его удаляет или наоборот добавляет.
Это чудо которое написал, будет сортировать данные как фильтр, что выбрал то и отображается(Как на сайте, ну или почти=))

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Смотрите есть, один комбобокс "Производитель" я его выбираю, и там значение пусть будет "Nissan" к примеру...
И у всех остальных комбобоксов (Модель, скорость, тип ну и т.д) должны отрисоватся по выбранному Производителю...
Допустим у Nissan тип кузова 'седан' а в комбобоксе тип кузова есть еще и 'Люкс' вопрос как мне этот люкс и все остальные типы убрать, оставив все подходящиее под Производитель

Comment: Проще всего - выбрали Ниссан - очистили все дочерние комбобоксы - заполнили их подходящими значениями.

Comment: Ааа, не тут то было, когда я всё очищаю, потом выбираю снова, комбобокс очищает значение еще до того как сортировать значение по производителю, значение Производителя не доходит до сортировочной функции, я вот просто не знаю где или как её правильно разместить что бы значение комбобокса можно было выбирать, тоесть что бы оно дошло до функции, остортировало, оставило выбранное значение этого комбобокса...
Я ж ведь кроме Производителя могу и выбирать изначально и тип кузова а потом уже и Производителя, ну и т.д

Comment: При чем тут сортировка? Если было выбрано какое-то значение в дочернем КБ, то сохраняйте его, очищайте и заполняйте КБ заново и выбирайте сохраненное значение, если оно есть в КБ.

Comment: ИМХО, вопрос нужно переписывать, добавляя в новую редакцию, то что из Вас вытащили в комментариях.

Comment: Кароче люди это как Фильтр на сайте, что выбрал то и отрисовалось, а всё остальное очищается(неподходящие под выброное)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно заполнять второй комбобокс после смены значений в первом.

Схема следующая:
У первого комбобокса подписываетесь на событие SelectedValueChanged.
Пример: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

В обработчике события изменения значения первого комбобокса смотрите, какое значение выбрано. На основе этого заполняете остальные комбобоксы:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
           var selectedManufacturer = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            // производитель найден, установим данные в других списках
            SetManufacturerValues(selectedManufacturer);
        }
    }
private void SetManufacturerValues(string manufacturer)
{
      ComboBoxBodyType.Items = BodiesDataSource.Where(b => b.ManufacturerName == manufacturer);
 ... 
 // остальные свойства
}
```

В приведённом примере устанавливается тип кузова для выбранного производителя. 
Из некого источника данных о типах кузовов - у вас он будет свой - мы выбираем только те, что соответствуют производителю. И их используем как источник данных для выпадающего списка.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, но это структура заполнение у меня уже есть)
У меня проблема в другом, не могу очистить комбобоксы, точнее очищаю, но при выборе ничего не происходит, тоесть он сначала все элементы Combobox уничтожает, а функция спрашивает 'Что ты мне принёс, а комбобокс "Пусто"...'я не могу заставить его
---------------------
У меня все Combobox подписаны на события, и при вызове он сначала очищает все элементы, а потом понятия не имеет что я выбрал... Вот гадаю как правильно очищать комбобоксы...

Comment: Не надо очищать комбобоксы, просто меняйте значение их свойства Items, каждый раз присваивая отфильтрованные значения. Тем самым вы просто замените все данные, старые уйдут, новые появятся.

Comment: Не совсем понял, Items.Add ? Items.AddRange ? Items.Remove ? Я не понял что вы имели ввиду если поставить Items.Add то он будет просто добавлять к существующим строкам новое значение

Comment: Items = ваш источник данных. Не надо clear, remove, ничего кроме присваивания. Старый набор данных исчезнет